# Create text boxes that change colour when hovered over

Tags: text, colors, hover

I am trying to create text-box hyperlinks for my website. I want transparent boxes until hovered over then i want to box to change colour but not the text. i was wondering if their was a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you'll want to add background-color: yourcolor to the hover pseudo class.

Here's an example for you:

```
<!-- Here's the HTML -->
<div class="myDiv">
  <p>Here is some text and then you will be <a href="mylink.html">linking</a> to another site</p>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you'll have:

```
.myDiv a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Pretty Simple.